# This JavaScript code is not working in an HTML5 application

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple application in [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) with JavaScript. It's supposed to play a random sound, when you push the button.

It works fine, when uploaded to a website, but it doesen't work on my smartphone.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function playSounds() {
                var sounds = new Array(
                    "musik/shut the f**k up.mp3",
                    "musik/My gun's bigger than yours!.mp3"
                );
                var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));
                $("#element").html("<embed src=\"" + sounds[index] + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"false\" />");
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body= "javascript:playSounds()">
        <button onClick="playSounds()">
            LAUGH</button>
        <div id="element">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I copied the content in file `jquery.min.js` from a site and linked it directly in the application to the mainpage, where the sound needs to play.

The source is here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js

I tried debugging the JavaScript code, but I can't seem to find the issue.

How do I solve this?

Comment: jQuery 1.3 is really old, you should update to 1.8.3 instead unless you have some very specific needs. It's located here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: Thanks :) do you know how to use the audio tag with this, to play a random sound on the push of a button? :) trying to find out how to the audio tag to good use, but it dosent seem easy

Answer (score 3):

Mobile devices in general do not support `<embed>`.

Your use of `<embed>` shows you have an imperfect understanding of what an "HTML5 app" is. Such an app would use `<audio>` and check `canPlayType("audio/mpeg")` to see if the browser supports MP3 playback.

Comment: I tried to upload the code to a website, where it work's from a computer, then i visited the url from an andorid and an iphone. The javascript code, dosent seem to work on smartphones. Is there a possible way to work around this?

Comment: Kolink >> Yes this is my first attempt, to make an app. How do i use audio instead of embed? Is there a tutorial on how to make this work?

Comment: I tied to edit the code to this, but i dosen't work correctly, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? :): $("#element").html("<audio src=\"" + sounds[index] + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"false\" controls=\"controls\"/></audio>");